# How to include array in $result->fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php

I don't know how to include arrays in $result->fetch_assoc.

I just want to include countryName[1] and categoryName[2] for each row in $result

```
$sql = "SELECT pic, title, address, map_id, category FROM ap_234 WHERE 
COALESCE(pic, '') != '' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT substring(post_content, 13, LENGTH(post_content) 
-14), post_title FROM ap_235 WHERE post_content LIKE '[abc id%' AND post_title 
NOT IN ('a', 'b')";
$countryName = $conn->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT category_name FROM ap_255_categories WHERE category_name 
NOT IN ('a', 'b' , 'c', 'd')";
$categoryName = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<br> <img src="'.$row['pic'].'"><br>Name: '. $row['title']. '<br>Coordinates: ' . $row['address'] . '<br>Country: ' . $countryName[1] . '<br>Category: ' . $categoryName[0] . '<br>';
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Error message: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$countryName` is SQL result, not array of result. Prepare `$countryName` array first.

```
$countryNameResult = $conn->query($sql);
$countryName = [];
while($row = $countryNameResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $countryName[] = $row; // or direct any column from DB, $row['col']
}
```

The same with `$categoryName`.

Comment: @simlev: ah, sorry, typo... Updated.